# Destructor and smart pointers giving C2541

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use some vectors of shared_ptr in my program, but doing so gives me a C2541-error: "delete": objects that are no pointers can't be deleted. I figured out it has something to do with the destructors of my classes (at least with one of them...) so i tried changing them - without success :(
My application contains a class A, which holds two vectors: one of shared_ptrs to objects of class B and of shared_ptrs to objects of class A.
Here are some parts of my code:

```
//A.cpp
A::~A(void)
{
    for(std::vector<BPtr>::iterator it = allBs.begin(); it != allBs.end(); ++it) 
    {   //loop that deletes all Bs
        delete it->get();
    }

    for(std::vector<APtr>::iterator it = allAs.begin(); it != allAs.end(); ++it) 
    {    //loop that (should) delete all As (and their As and Bs)
        delete it->get();
        delete it.operator*;
    }
}

//A.h
class A
{
public:
typedef std::shared_ptr<A> APtr; 
typedef std::shared_ptr<B> BPtr; 
// some more stuff
private:
std::vector<BPtr> allBs;
std::vector<APtr> allAs;
}
```

I'm getting the error twice: one comes from the line
    delete it.operator*;
and the other one is caused inside of memory.h.
I first had an extra recursive function which deleted the tree and was called by the destructor, but after a little thinking I thought that calling "delete" inside the destructor (line "delete it->get();") would do just the same.

Comment: If you're using `shared_ptr` why do you need to `delete` them?

Comment: Would it be the correct way to just clear() the two vectors? This gave the me error aswell.

Comment: Are you concerned about a recursive loop in the structures? Perhaps you could show the code for 'B'?

Comment: You probably don't want to put anything in the destructor except for ways to clear memory for members of A which are not smart pointers. Also, you might be concerned about the destructor for B.

Comment: Class B does only contain a string, nothing to be shown there :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You're doing it wrong.*

The entire purpose of smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr` is that you do not have to manually delete what they point at. Indeed, you *must not* delete it manually. The smart pointer assumes ownership of the pointee—it will delete it itself when applicable. For `std::shared_ptr`, "when applicable" means "when the last `std::shared_ptr` pointing to the object is destroyed."

So just remove the destructor altogether, you don't need it. When the vectors are destroyed, they will destroy all of the contained `std::shared_ptr`s. This will reduce the reference count of the pointees. If any go to zero, they will be `delete`d automatically (by the `shared_ptr` destructor).

Comment: That's the point that confuses me. I was getting the error without destructor aswell, that's why I added them.

Comment: @user3190009 Were you perhaps calling `delete p` where `p` is a `std::shared_ptr`? Anyway, if you have code which gives you an error you don't understand, you should ask a question about that code, not about some other code...

Comment: I already checked that before trying the idea with the destructor. I'm not even using "delete" anywhere in my code (except some comments, haha).
Well, the errors (twice the same actually) came from memory.h itself. From a place where (atleast I think so) the pointer tries to delete its pointee.

Comment: @user3190009 Well then, if you want help with that, construct an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) out of your code and post it as a new question (assuming the creation of the MCVE doesn't lead you straight to an answer, which it usually does).

Answer (score 1):

You can and must `delete` only things created with `new`. Only these exactly once, nothing else. Deletion can be done either "by hand"  or by letting a smart pointer like `std::shared_ptr` do it for you (which is a very good idea). When using smart pointers, you can (and should) get rid of the `new` in favor of `std::make_shared` or `std::make_unique`.

The same applies to `new[]` and `delete[]`.

This means that in your destructor there is no room for `delete` because you never `new`ed anything and have it owned by a raw pointer (which was good).

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to `delete` a `shared_ptr`'s contents, that's its job.  simply `reset` the smart pointer:

```
it->reset();
```